# Display and Formatting UTC Time On Static Website in Real-Time

Tags: javascript, html

My website currently displays UTC time like this:

`2022-03-22T23:38:25.748Z`

But I would like for it to be formatted like this:

`23:39:22 UTC`

Here is the javascript I have:

```
  <script type="text/javascript"> 
  function display_c(){
  var refresh=1000; // Refresh rate in milli seconds
  mytime=setTimeout('display_ct()',refresh)
  }
  
  function display_ct() {
  var x = new Date()
  var x1=x.toISOString();// changing the display to UTC string
  document.getElementById('ct').innerHTML = x1;
  tt=display_c();
   }

  <body onload=display_ct();><span id='ct' >
```

Can you help me format this? I've looked into using angular and searched other methods for implementing this but it seems that there are many ways to do this. The things I've tried do not display the format correctly. The code above is the closest solution I have found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new Date().toISOString().slice(11, 19) + ' UTC'
```

A nice and intentional property of the ISO datetime format is that most of the parts are always the same length.

Note that truncating, not rounding, is the correct behavior.

Comment: Everyone had good suggestions. I don't understand much about coding so it's hard for me to know which is best. This answer, for me, works very well. I like that I can use the same property and that I can customize the ending (UTC, GMT, Z, ZULU).

Answer (score 2):

Use the `Intl.DateTimeFormat` method for this as follows:

```js
  function display_c(){
    const refresh = 1000; 
    mytime = setTimeout('display_ct()',refresh)
  }
  
  function display_ct() {
    let dtf = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en-GB", { timeZone: "GMT", hour12: false, timeStyle: "long" });
    document.getElementById('ct').innerHTML = dtf.format( new Date() );
    tt = display_c();
   }

display_ct();
```

```html
<div id="ct"></div>
```

---

### Customization:

You can either use the various configuration options available to customize the format of the datetime, or use the following setup for displaying a custom String:

```js
  function display_ct() {
    let dtf = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en-GB", { timeZone: "GMT", hour12: false, timeStyle: "medium" });
    document.getElementById('ct').innerHTML = dtf.format( new Date() ) + " Zulu";
   }
```

Available configuration options: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. I'm wondering if it's possible to customize the UTC to "Z" or "Zulu" - UTC works perfectly but was wondering if that part of the code was customizable?

Comment: @hearsay I've updated the answer with a link to the available configuration options and a custom output with Zulu.

Answer (score 2):

This should produce the format you want to have.

```js
let date = new Date();
let utc_string = date.toUTCString().match(/..:..:.. .*/)[0];
console.log(utc_string);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a web to helping you. And i give an example to you too.
https://www.codevscolor.com/javascript-iso-utc

```js
const date = new Date('2022-03-22T23:38:25.748Z')

console.log(date.toString())
console.log(date.toUTCString())
```